# jQuery Dialog: Placing asp.net formview on dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, formview

I have a simple ASP.NET (VB) page set up and am trying to do something specific: ***place an asp.net formview on a dialog that opens whenever a specific gridview record is chosen.***

**Here is the symptom:** when I select a record, it triggers the dialog with the formview, but the formview is empty when it's supposed to contain the record selected in the gridview.

**Here is my question:** Can anyone tell me what I am missing? What do I need to add or do differently so that the formview contains the selected record.

Thanks in advance for any helpful advice.

**Here is the relevant jQuery code that defines the dialog:**

```
$("[id$=div_fvEditRecord]").dialog({
autoOpen:false,
modal:true,
resizable: true                
});
```

**Here is the code that launches the dialog:**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select"  onclientclick="$(&quot;[id$=div_fvEditRecord]&quot;).dialog( &quot;open&quot;); return false;" Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Here is the div containing the formview that goes on the dialog:**

```
<div id="div_fvEditRecord" style="display:none">                
    <asp:FormView ID="fvEditRecord" runat="server" Caption="Edit selected record" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="sdsTable_RandomStuff" DefaultMode="Edit" 
        EmptyDataText="No records have been chosen">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            ID:
            <asp:Label ID="IDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            <br />
            Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
            <br />
            Date:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate_add" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>' />
            <br />
            Time:
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime_add" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Time") %>' />
            <br />
            Count:
            <asp:TextBox ID="CountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Count") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</div>
```

**To get a better sense of context, here is the full asp.net file.**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    Private Sub UpdateViews(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles fvEditRecord.ItemInserted
        gvViewRecords.DataBind()
    End Sub
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Dialog Form Test</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.timepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <link href="Scripts/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id$=txtDate_add]").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "m/dd/yy",
                showAnim: "slide",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });

            $("[id$=txtTime_add]").timepicker({
                scrollDefaultNow: true
            });

            $("[id$=div_fvEditRecord]").dialog({
                autoOpen:false,
                modal:true,
                resizable: true                
            });           
        });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:sqldatasource ID="sdsTable_RandomStuff" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Sandbox1ConnectionString %>" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Name], [Date], [Time], [Count] FROM [RandomStuff] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvViewRecords" Name="ID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:sqldatasource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsView_RandomStuff" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Sandbox1ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [RandomStuff]" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [RandomStuff] WHERE [ID] = @original_ID AND (([Name] = @original_Name) OR ([Name] IS NULL AND @original_Name IS NULL)) AND (([Date] = @original_Date) OR ([Date] IS NULL AND @original_Date IS NULL)) AND (([Time] = @original_Time) OR ([Time] IS NULL AND @original_Time IS NULL)) AND (([Count] = @original_Count) OR ([Count] IS NULL AND @original_Count IS NULL))" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [RandomStuff] ([Name], [Date], [Time], [Count]) VALUES (@Name, @Date, @Time, @Count)" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [RandomStuff] SET [Name] = @Name, [Date] = @Date, [Time] = @Time, [Count] = @Count WHERE [ID] = @original_ID AND (([Name] = @original_Name) OR ([Name] IS NULL AND @original_Name IS NULL)) AND (([Date] = @original_Date) OR ([Date] IS NULL AND @original_Date IS NULL)) AND (([Time] = @original_Time) OR ([Time] IS NULL AND @original_Time IS NULL)) AND (([Count] = @original_Count) OR ([Count] IS NULL AND @original_Count IS NULL))">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_Date" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Time" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Count" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Date" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Time" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Count" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Date" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Time" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Count" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="original_Date" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Time" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Count" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <h1>
            jQuery Skill Development</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Use Datepicker on a textbox in Formview</li>
            <li>Use Timepicker on a textbox in Formview</li>
            <li>Place Formview on a Dialog for new entries</li>
        </ul>

        <asp:GridView ID="gvViewRecords" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
            DataSourceID="sdsView_RandomStuff" Caption="View/Edit Records">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Select" 
                            onclientclick="$(&quot;[id$=div_fvEditRecord]&quot;).dialog( &quot;open&quot;); return false;" 
                            Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Date" 
                    SortExpression="Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" DataFormatString="{0:t}" HeaderText="Time" 
                    SortExpression="Time" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Count" HeaderText="Count" SortExpression="Count" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <div id="div_fvEditRecord" style="display:none">                
        <asp:FormView ID="fvEditRecord" runat="server" Caption="Edit selected record" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="sdsTable_RandomStuff" DefaultMode="Edit" 
            EmptyDataText="No records have been chosen">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                ID:
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                <br />
                Name:
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                Date:
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate_add" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>' />
                <br />
                Time:
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime_add" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Time") %>' />
                <br />
                Count:
                <asp:TextBox ID="CountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Count") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update: I changed the way I opened the dialog: by means of a separate function defined in the head script block rather than in the onClientClick property of the gridview.       '$(document).ready(function Load_FV_Dialog() {
            $("[id$=div_fvEditRecord]").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });'

Comment: Because I'm a new user with a low reputation, it won't let me declare that I found an answer to my question. Please see my previous comment.  Problem solved -- don't know why, but this symptom is solved.  Thanks for those who responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way I opened the dialog: by means of a separate function defined in the head script block rather than in the onClientClick property of the gridview.

```
    $(document).ready( function Load_FV_Dialog() { 
       $("[id$=div_fvEditRecord]").dialog("open"); 
       return false; 
    });
```

I called the function in my gridview in onClientClick by calling "Load_FV_Dialog()" rather than letting onClientClick = the function definition.

*This* problem I asked for help on is now solved: when I select a record to edit, the dialog shows the formview with the selected row.

However, when I click update, null values sent rather than the updated values.  That, however, is a different issue I will need to research.  Thank you for those who responded, they helped me consider options I might not have thought of on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `dsplay:none` property in

```
<div id="div_fvEditRecord" style="display:none">
```

try removing it

Comment: Sorry. That didn't solve the problem.  Besides, the purpose of that style is so that it only appears on the dialog -- not on the main page itself.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this

```
$("[id$=div_fvEditRecord]")
```

should be replaced with

```
  $("[id$='div_fvEditRecord']") or $("#div_fvEditRecord")
```

Comment: I followed your advice and followed this format: '("[id$='div_fvEditRecord']")'.  No changes observed.